# Multiple fetch in ThenFetch

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've an associated entity with `<many-to-one>` and that entity has two `<many-to-one>` that I want to fetch at once. I can achieve this by this query:

```
 var tshead = session.Query<MainEntity>()
                .Fetch(r=>r.FirstAssoc).ThenFetch(p=>p.Other)
                .Fetch(r=>r.FirstAssoc).ThenFetch(p=>p.Another)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

As you can see I had to wrote twice `.Fetch(r=>r.FirstAssoc)` 
I'm sure I can avoid this but I cant figure out how. Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it, unless `Fetch(r=>r.FirstAssoc.Another)` works, which I doubt.

Comment: @Diego thanks, your doubt is confirmed ( expression too complex exception ). But it would be nice to have.

Comment: I have this exact same issue, although my FirstAssoc is a collection so it is FetchMany.ThenFetch.FetchMany.ThenFetch. Would love a solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select a specific 'MainEntity' then you can do it using QueryOver like so:

```
 FirstAssoc firstAssoc = null;
 Other other = null;
 Another another = null;

 tshead = session.QueryOver<MainEntity>()
               .Where(x => x.Id == id)
               .JoinAlias(x => x.FirstAssoc, () => firstAssoc)
               .JoinAlias(() => firstAssoc.Other, () => other)
               .JoinAlias(() => firstAssoc.Another, () => another)
               .SingleOrDefault();
```

I've written about it here:

http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/04/nhibernate-querying-relationships-are-depth/

You can't do:

*One-Many-Many*

only *One-Many-One*.

I'm not sure you can do *Many-Many-One*, transforming that would be too difficult.

Comment: @Diego - CC you since you may be interested.

Comment: +1, but you are using QueryOver, can we achieve the same with linqtonh ? PS your blog is really interesting:)

Comment: @Felice - Not sure if you can do it with Query<T>, i suspect it isn't possible, but I'll have a play this weekend see how far I can get. Any reason you can't use QueryOver? Thanks for the comment about my blog :) appreciated.

Comment: Well I can eventually resort on using queryover, but I'm just worried about having many API merged together.

Comment: If you're using the repository pattern then those details are hidden away. I primarily use QueryOver but sometimes fall back onto Query, HQL and if required, Native SQL.